# How to exclude directories from xargs rsync?

Tags: linux, bash

So I'm trying to set up a bash script for incremental backups using `rsync` with `xargs` to use multiple threads on Ubuntu Server 20.042 LTS. There's a handful of directories that I want to exclude, but I can't seem to figure out the way to do that. Currently I'm piping `ls` to `xargs` which then executes `rsync` with 8 processes:

```
# Create the archive and begin the backup.
cd /
ls --indicator-style none \
  --ignore={"bin","boot","cdrom","data","dev","init*","lib","lib64","lost+found"} \
  --ignore={"media","mnt","proc","root","run","sbin","snap","srv","swap.img","sys"} \
  --ignore={"tmp","vmlinuz*"} | xargs --max-args 1 --max-procs 8 -I % \
  rsync --archive --compress --delete --ignore-missing-args --recursive --verbose \
  --link-dest "${backup_link}" "%" \
  --exclude={"*tmp*","*.cache"} \
  "${backup_path}"
```

For some reason, it's still trying to use `rsync` on the directories that I've ignored with the `ls` command. I've tried setting `rsync` to exclude the directories instead:

```
# Create the archive and begin the backup.
cd /
ls --indicator-style none | xargs --max-args 1 --max-procs 8 -I % \
  rsync --archive --compress --delete --ignore-missing-args --recursive \
  --exclude={"/bin","/boot","/cdrom","/data/mysql","/data/backup","/dev"} \
  --exclude={"/initrd.img","/initrd.img.old","/lib","/lib64","/lost+found","/media"} \
  --exclude={"/mnt","/proc","/root","/run","/sbin","/snap","/srv","/swap.img","/sys"} \
  --exclude={"**/tmp","/vmlinuz*","*.cache"} \
  --link-dest "${backup_link}" "%" "${backup_path}"
```

Which still tries to backup the files that I want to exclude.

The reason I'm trying to run multiple threads is that this script is set to execute every 15 minutes via `crontab` and, without the multiple processes, it's barely taking less than 15 minutes. Later in the script, it then copies that backup (also using `rsync`) to an SMB server, which is a huge bottleneck with all of the small files.

Is there something that I'm missing here? Or is there a better way to accomplish this? This is a production server, so I'd really like to avoid installing third-party utilities.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a factor here, but [it's generally bad practice to parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Try using globbing or `find` instead.

Comment: If you take `xargs` out of the mix, does it work properly?

Comment: @wjandrea `find` was the first thing that I tried, but I was having the same issue, as well as it was also enumerating the subdirectories instead of just the parents. Taking `xargs` out and just piping `ls` seems to cause `rsync` to not know what it's parsing and just failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: in my first answer, I indicated that your syntax for the `--ignore` option did not work on Mint 19 (ls GNU 8.28).  Well it does, so this part is now removed!

---

I always try to use `find` for such tasks, and not trust `ls`.  You can use this:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "bin" -print
```

Use `! -name "XXX"` sections many times for your exclusions.

---

Or my preferred method, since I find it easier to read:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | egrep -Ev "bin|boot"
```

You can have as many patterns inside the `egrep` match, separated by a `|`.  In this context, `|` is like `or`.  So here it says to filter out "bin" or "boot".